# Choice command only returns errorelevel=0 inside a nest of if's

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I execute the call choice command inside an IF's nest, but it only returns "errorlevel=0". When I run out of if's it works correctly and returns the value 1 when I select y=yes.

I used the command as shown in the link:
[properly-use-choice-inside-of-call-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491665/batch-how-to-properly-use-choice-inside-of-call-function)

Command code:

```
if "%opm%"=="1" (
 if "%sel%"=="out" (
  for /f skip^=4 %%e in ('echo;prompt $E^|cmd') do (set "_$E=%%e")
  set /p "'=%_$E%[31mThere are no files in the folder! Do you want to search another file? %_$E%[31m" <nul
  call choice /n /m "(y=yes/n=no)" 
  if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
   goto anotherfile
  )else (
   endlocal & goto notfound
  )
 )
)
```

Whichever option I choose returns errorlevel=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact you are expanding the variable within a code block. Environment variables within codeblocks are expanded when the code block is read into memory, prior to it's execution. One option to resolve this is to enable delayed expansion prior to the code block with the command: `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and to expand variables requiring a runtime value with exclamation marks: `!variablename!`

Another solution would be to use a for /f loop to capture the key pressed in response to the choice command:

```
    Echo([Y]es [N]o
    For /f Delims^= %%G in ('choice /n /c:YN')Do if /I "%%G"=="Y" goto:anotherfile
    Goto:notfound
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks!